OpenSCAP schematron validation failure
When performing the OpenSCAP validation on a fresh installation of Oracle Linux 9.4 the first five Schematron validations pass, but on the "global schematron validation using the source data stream schematron" it fails, it throws a very long list of warnings and ends with the following;
Global schematron validation using the source data stream schematron: FAIL
Complete result of schematron validation of '/usr/share/xml/scap/ssg/content/ssg-ol9-ds.xml': FAIL
OpenSCAP Error: Invalid SCAP Source Datastream (1.3) content in /usr/share/xml/scap/ssg/content/ssg-ol9-ds.xml. [/builddir/build/BUILD/openscap-1.3.10/src/source/oscap_source.c:391]
exit code = 2 not ok
Any help would be much appreciated.
